# With Drop down menu with text box, pass values to php

Tags: php, html

Initially, I had a text box like this:

```
<input type=\"text\" name="+"\""+test1+"\""+" size=\"80\"></td>
```

Now, I want the it to be a drop down list where the user can either select from the list or enter his/her own values, like this:

```
    <input type='text' ...    list='listid'>
    <datalist id='listid' >
      <option label='one' value='one: '>
      <option label='two ' value='two '>
      <option label='somehting else' value='something else '>
      ...
    </datalist>
```

test1 is a variable and when I used a text box, I used test1 variable to pass the value entered to the php script.

How should I do it now?
Also, what exactly do list id and datalist id do?

Comment: where is like this ? :)

Comment: Please add the code to show how it is now and how you want to change.

Comment: Add your code for what you did

Comment: I'm sorry.. Added the code..

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are trying to do? Is it similar to this?You can give `value="something"` and pass in php

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7dc/)

Comment: I' sorry.. Didnt realize that the code was missing.. I have added the code.. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this as well as you where doing by input without datalist.

The only thing that datalist is doing, is just suggesting some options to user.

After writing or choosing from list, the value in text box will be passed to PHP script.

Source: [W3schools datalist example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_datalist)